Suspend process: `screen <process>`?
The normal job control of ^Z does not work when calling <process> ffmpeg to screen directly from the bash cli:
e.g.,
screen ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i /tmp/mpd.fifo -f mpegts -b:a 128k -acodec libopus zmq:tcp://0.0.0.0:5555 &>> /var/log/mpd/ffmpeg.log
^A^D

or
screen -dmS ffmpeg ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i /tmp/mpd.fifo -f mpegts -b:a 128k -acodec libopus zmq:tcp://0.0.0.0:5555 &>> /var/log/mpd/ffmpeg.log

I have had occasion where I wanted to stop that ffmpeg job and the normal screen -r ^Z suspend does not work.
I've come to the assumption that this is because screen is working in a non-interactive shell which is great and all, but I still want to be able to call ffmpeg to screen via a script and be able to suspend it and have not come up with a way around this problem.
I tried a few things including defshell -/bin/bash in ~/.screenrc but without success.
I do not [presently] have/use tmux but want to consider all best options.

Send a SIGSTOP to the process to suspend it; SIGCONT to resume it. This is more or less the underlying mechanism of job-control-based suspend/resume, but slightly more direct and doesn't require a shell to set up job control (though it would make weird things happen when there is a shell).
kill -STOP $(pidof ffmpeg)

